# How to redirect from "index.html" to "www.example.com"?

Tags: html

I want to redirect from www.example.com/index.html to just www.example.com. I have changed my internal links to remove the "index.html" but was wondering if I should redirect it completely?

If so, how do i do this?

Comment: What you are trying to do. be clear and post some code where you stuck?

Comment: I have created a html website, I have made a index.htm file which is redirecting to home page, www.example.com/index.htm. I want to remove index.htm after the domain name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<a href="www.example.com">redirect<a>
```

Use tag  like shown above in index.html